# "Element is already the logical child of another element" Exception Even When Collection of Items Cleared

Tags: c#, wpf, exception

The occurring exception is self-explanatory:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Element already has a logical
> parent. It must be detached from the old parent before it is attached
> to a new one.'

However, it does not make sense that it is being thrown at the end of the following method, which is an event handler that updates the icon shown in the NavigationItem (a UserControl) triggered by a separate executing thread that checks the connection status and triggers the event if the connection status changed (i.e. was disconnected -> now connected, and vice versa).

The method where the exception thrown at the end:

```
void OnMachineConnectionStatusChangedHandler(object source, EventArgs e)
{
    Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {

        Machine machine = source as Machine;

                    // obtain the TreeViewItem representing this machine in the navigation tree

                    lock (_navigationTree)
        {
            foreach (TreeViewItem navigationItem in _navigationTree.Items)
            {

                NavigationItem machineNavItem = navigationItem.Header as NavigationItem;

                if (machineNavItem.Machine.Equals(machine))
                {
                    lock (machineNavItem)
                    {
                        machineNavItem.Refresh(); // changes shown icon

                                    if (machine.Connected)
                        {
                            if (navigationItem.Items.Count > 0)
                                navigationItem.Items.Clear(); // clear prev. items shown under

                                        TreeViewItem TO = new TreeViewItem()
                            {
                                Header = "TO",
                                Padding = new Thickness(0, 2.5, 10, 2.5)
                            };
                            TreeViewItem WO = new TreeViewItem()
                            {
                                Header = "WO",
                                Padding = new Thickness(0, 2.5, 10, 2.5)
                            };
                            TreeViewItem EWO = new TreeViewItem()
                            {
                                Header = "EWO",
                                Padding = new Thickness(0, 2.5, 10, 2.5)
                            };

                            List<int> machineHolds = machine.getActiveHoldNumbers();

                            if (machineHolds.Count > 1)
                            {
                                foreach (int hold in machineHolds)
                                {
                                    TreeViewItem holdItem = new TreeViewItem() { Header = ("#" + hold) };
                                    TO.Items.Add(hold);
                                    WO.Items.Add(hold);
                                    EWO.Items.Add(hold);
                                }

                            }

                            navigationItem.Items.Add(TO);
                            navigationItem.Items.Add(WO);
                            navigationItem.Items.Add(EWO);

                            navigationItem.IsExpanded = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        this.UpdateLayout();
    }); // here, the Exception is thrown
}
```

I did debug with VS, stepping through every line and overall, nothing throws the Exception, except at the end.

For reference, here is the structure of the UserControl NavigationItem if it of any relevance:

```
public partial class NavigationItem : UserControl
{
    // fields
    private Machine _machine;

    // properties
    public Machine Machine
    {
        get { return _machine; }
    }

    public NavigationItem(Machine machine)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _machine = machine;

        if (_machine.Connected)
            _statusImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Resources/Checkmark-Icon.png"));
        else
            _statusImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Resources/X-Icon.png"));

        _machineNameLabel.Content = _machine.Name;
    }

    public void Refresh()
    {
        if (_machine.Connected)
            _statusImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Resources/Checkmark-Icon.png"));
        else
            _statusImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Resources/X-Icon.png"));
    }
}
```

Any help or guidance would be very much appreciated as to why that exception is being thrown and remedied.

Comment: There must be some `UIElement` in your code that is used at least twice. Each `UIElement` is only allowed to be added to the visual tree once. This happens when you write bad code like this. You usually should operate on data models and not on view elements. This is where the power of WPF and XAML shines. You should create a collection of data items and bind this items to the `TreeView`. Your data items should reflect the tree structure you need.

Comment: Then you define a `DataTemplate` or [`HierarchicalDataTemplate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate?view=netcore-3.1#examples) to actually layout the visual UI appearance of the data item. You would add your user control to this template. WPF then automatically creates the item containers like `TreeViewItem` and applies the template to each to them their look. This is how every data view works or should be generated. [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview).

Comment: Following this concept, your code becomes cleaner and will feel more natural especially when writing dynamic controls. You will _never_ get this exception thrown at you again, which means your code would also become more robust. Always data first. This is why WPF and MVVM go together as one.

Comment: @BionicCode Even without the full MVVM, databinding alone eliminates practically any possibility of an error. Creating and inserting UI elements comes from the early days of ASP.NET when tons of articles demonstrated it this way. At the time, it was a bit hard to get your head around how databinding works. I shocked people still do it this way.

Comment: @ATL_DEV This the result of misconception. Especially beginners of software development didn't understand or know those abstract levels introduced by design patterns. Since you click buttons, their perception of an application is 100% _UI driven_. UI must shine, the rest is second or serves the UI. They think like a consumer. If you are a true developer you start to care about archictectural aspects like layers and models - your perceptions becomes _data driven_. Many people have trouble to grasp this abstract levels and so they stick to the more intuitive way of UI driven "development".

Comment: @Sometimes I get the feeling many people are also too lazy to learn anything. When you are a seasoned WinForms dev and you are probably fed up learning something new or to improve  you continue to do it the classic WinForms way - even if it's more complicated and error prone. If you are not driven by making things perfect and skillfully, what craftsmanship should be some stints are ok.

Comment: @BionicCode  I agree. I think white-boarding or technical interviews are the real source of the problem. They weed out the talented engineers. To give an example, back in the early 90s, I once failed a technical interview for the most ridiculous reason. I was supposed to write code to copy a string in C. I had just completed it the problem and a 21 year old looked it over and said "This can be written in one line of code."  Just as he was about to walk away, I asked him "Well, how is that possible?"  He then wrote on the margin of my paper, "strcpy(src, dest);"  LOL!

Comment: @ATL_DEV There are way too many clowns out there. I wonder if there is a correlation between this and the messed up software projects/products. Some are stuck on a certain low level, but there they excel (in their bubble). Because they act like they are genius some HR managers buy it.

Comment: @ATL_DEV I was once having a heavy argument with my dev lead that days. I was hired quite recently and came to notice that one dev had serious troubles because his library had tons of conflicting type definitions with the framework (MFC). I ask him why they are not using namespaces. He didn't know what I was talking about. Dev lead came in, I started to talk about namespaces, he trying to shut me up saying C++ has no namespaces. The _whole_ dev team was poorly skilled. Management was never questioning this. Dev lead knew how to sell it.

Comment: @ATL_DEV  I had situations like this a few times. In my experience dev leads gather around people of they own skill level or (preferably) lower - maintaining their bubble. If he is highly skilled, so will be the devs in the company. It's about ego I guess. You just need to be good in selling. He sold to HR managers that you are too unqualified although he might just feared you. If he fails to manage projects he just has to sell it. Nobody will ask if he picked the wrong dev team.

Comment: @ATL_DEV Success is 80% selling, 10% skill, 10% luck. No matter if politics or job. Most high skilled individuals are not in charge. They are always on the road, because of so much clowns (in charge).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out after commenting out code to narrow done what line/section is the culprit.

The issue is in:

```
foreach (int hold in machineHolds)
{
    TreeViewItem holdItem = new TreeViewItem()
    { Header = ("#" + hold) };
    TO.Items.Add(hold);
    WO.Items.Add(hold);
    EWO.Items.Add(hold);
}
```

The problem is that I initialize a single TreeViewItem, holdItem, but attempt to add it to 3 different "parent" TreeViewItems. Thus, the solution is to:

```
foreach (int hold in machineHolds)
{
    foreach (int type = 0; type < 3; type++)
    {
        TreeViewItem holdItem = new TreeViewItem()
            { Header = ("#" + hold) };
        switch (type){
            case 0:
                TO.Items.Add(hold);
                break;
            case 1:
                WO.Items.Add(hold);
                break;
            case 2:
                EWO.Items.Add(hold);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can really make your job a thousand times easier by using databinding. You'll also reduce your code size significantly.  Doing it this way will eventually cause you problems.